# Getting all children in a LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, programmatically-created

How to get all children in order to use them later?

```
LinearLayout createRow(LinearLayout parrent, int id, int orientation, int color){
    LinearLayout cell = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams rowParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    rowParams.weight = 1;
    rowParams.setMargins(5,2,5,2);

    cell.setLayoutParams(rowParams);

    cell.setBackgroundColor(color);
    cell.setOrientation(orientation);
    cell.setId(id);

    parrent.addView(cell);

    cell.setOnClickListener(cellListener);
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the number of children on your layout using the `getChildCount()`
Once you have that you can loop through them like this:

```
int childCount = cell.getChildCount();
View child;
for(int i=0; i++; i<childCount)
{
   child = cell.getChildAt(i);
   // do what you want with each child element
}
```